# how to remove object from array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays`totalArray` and `selectionArray`, these values are always dynamic but for example purpose I given below that arrays, Now I want to remove `selectionArray` from `totalArray` using id not index because I have only five values per page. so if I remove value using index then it is removing values from other page also because page wise index is same found. so how to remove object using id? I use splice but is using other methods or any other solution available?

```
  totalArray = [
     {id: 1, city: 'LONDON'},
     {id: 2, city: 'PARIS'},
     {id: 3, city: 'NEW YORK'},
     {id: 4, city: 'BERLIN'},
     {id: 5, city: 'MADRID'},
     {id: 6, city: 'ROME'},
     {id: 7, city: 'DUBLIN'},
     {id: 8, city: 'ATHENS'},
     {id: 9, city: 'ANKARA'},
     {id: 10, city: 'MOSCOW'},
  ]      

   selectionArray = [
     {id: 6, city: 'ROME'},
     {id: 7, city: 'DUBLIN'},
     {id: 8, city: 'ATHENS'},
     {id: 9, city: 'ANKARA'},
     {id: 10, city: 'MOSCOW'},
  ]

  selectionArray.forEach((item, i) => { 
      totalArray.splice(item.id, 1);
  });
```

Comment: You want to mutate the original array or create a new one without the mentioned elements? In the later case, take a look to `Array.filter()`. In this particular case, maybe yo can use `let newArray = totalArray.filter(({id}) => id < 6)`

Comment: `.findIndex()`, so you know which index to `.splice()`. Or `.filter()`, where `.find()` return true.

Comment: Do the object have the same references? Do they come from the same source? In that case, you can use indexOf.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to **alter the original array**, here is a solution following this approach:

- Acquire the `id` of the looped item selectionArray, taking advantage of `array.forEach`.
- Find, in total array, the element with the same index of the looped one.
- Acquire its index, and splice the element from the array.

This should be pretty similar to what you've tried to achieve with your code, I've tried to stay as close as possible to your try.

```js
const totalArray = [
     {id: 1, city: 'LONDON'},
     {id: 2, city: 'PARIS'},
     {id: 3, city: 'NEW YORK'},
     {id: 4, city: 'BERLIN'},
     {id: 5, city: 'MADRID'},
     {id: 6, city: 'ROME'},
     {id: 7, city: 'DUBLIN'},
     {id: 8, city: 'ATHENS'},
     {id: 9, city: 'ANKARA'},
     {id: 10, city: 'MOSCOW'},
  ],   
  selectionArray = [
     {id: 6, city: 'ROME'},
     {id: 7, city: 'DUBLIN'},
     {id: 8, city: 'ATHENS'},
     {id: 9, city: 'ANKARA'},
     {id: 10, city: 'MOSCOW'},
  ];

selectionArray.forEach(({id: uid}) => {
  totalArray.splice(
    totalArray.indexOf(totalArray.find(({id}) => uid === id)),
    1
  );
});
console.log(totalArray);
```

Please note that if both array elements comes from the same array source you can simply use `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best option.
Basically it cycles both arrays and when the id is matching it removes the key from the first array

```js
totalArray = [
     {id: 1, city: 'LONDON'},
     {id: 2, city: 'PARIS'},
     {id: 3, city: 'NEW YORK'},
     {id: 4, city: 'BERLIN'},
     {id: 5, city: 'MADRID'},
     {id: 6, city: 'ROME'},
     {id: 7, city: 'DUBLIN'},
     {id: 8, city: 'ATHENS'},
     {id: 9, city: 'ANKARA'},
     {id: 10, city: 'MOSCOW'},
  ]      

   selectionArray = [
     {id: 1, city: 'LONDON'},     
     {id: 7, city: 'DUBLIN'},
     {id: 8, city: 'ATHENS'},
     {id: 9, city: 'ANKARA'},
     {id: 10, city: 'MOSCOW'},
  ]
  
  for (key in totalArray){
    
    for (removeKey in selectionArray){
      if (totalArray[key].id == selectionArray[removeKey].id){
        totalArray.splice(key,1)
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(totalArray)
```

Comment: your `selectionArray` is different from the one in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove items from an array.
Combine this with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) you can ensure that the item is not found in the removal array.

```js
const totalArray = [
  { id: 1, city: "LONDON" },
  { id: 2, city: "PARIS" },
  { id: 3, city: "NEW YORK" },
  { id: 4, city: "BERLIN" },
  { id: 5, city: "MADRID" },
  { id: 6, city: "ROME" },
  { id: 7, city: "DUBLIN" },
  { id: 8, city: "ATHENS" },
  { id: 9, city: "ANKARA" },
  { id: 10, city: "MOSCOW" }
];

const selectionArray = [
  { id: 6, city: "ROME" },
  { id: 7, city: "DUBLIN" },
  { id: 8, city: "ATHENS" },
  { id: 9, city: "ANKARA" },
  { id: 10, city: "MOSCOW" }
];

const remainingArray = totalArray.filter(city =>
  selectionArray.every(selCity => selCity.id !== city.id)
);

console.log(remainingArray);
```

The `filter` function works by calling a callback for each item. If the callback returns `true` the item is kept. If the callback returns `false` the item is removed. The function returns the remaining values.

The `every` function works by calling a callback for each item in the array. If the callback returns `true` for all item in the array, the function returns `true`. If the callback returns `false` for any item then the function returns `false`.

For every `city` in `totalArray`, we check to see if the `id` is *not* in every single one of the cities from `selectionArray`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const totalArray = [
   {id: 1, city: 'LONDON'},
   {id: 2, city: 'PARIS'},
   {id: 3, city: 'NEW YORK'},
   {id: 4, city: 'BERLIN'},
   {id: 5, city: 'MADRID'},
   {id: 6, city: 'ROME'},
   {id: 7, city: 'DUBLIN'},
   {id: 8, city: 'ATHENS'},
   {id: 9, city: 'ANKARA'},
   {id: 10, city: 'MOSCOW'},
];  

const selectionArray = [
   {id: 6, city: 'ROME'},
   {id: 7, city: 'DUBLIN'},
   {id: 8, city: 'ATHENS'},
   {id: 9, city: 'ANKARA'},
   {id: 10, city: 'MOSCOW'},
];

// Using splice
// We loop over the "selectionArray" and use .findIndex() to find the index of each object.
const result_splice = [ ...totalArray ];
selectionArray.forEach( selection => {
  const index_in_totalArray = result_splice.findIndex( total => total.id === selection.id );
  result_splice.splice( index_in_totalArray, 1 );
});
console.log( 'RESULT_SPLICE' );
console.log( result_splice );

// Using .filter();
// We extract all the selected ids and then .filter() the "totalArray" to remove
// all items with an id found inside "selected_ids"
const selected_ids = selectionArray.map( selection => selection.id );
const result_includes = totalArray.filter( total => !selected_ids.includes( total.id ));
console.log( 'RESULT_INCLUDES' );
console.log( result_includes );

// Using .find()
// Almost the same as using .filter(), but instead of extracting the ids beforehand, we just loop over the "selectedArray" with .find()
const result_find = totalArray.filter( total => {
  return !selectionArray.find( selection => selection.id === total.id );
});
console.log( 'RESULT_FIND' );
console.log( result_find );

const json_splice = JSON.stringify( result_splice );
const json_includes = JSON.stringify( result_includes );
const json_find = JSON.stringify( result_find );
console.log( 'All results are equal:' );json_find && 
console.log( json_splice === json_includes && json_splice === json_find && json_includes === json_find );
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest and simplest way will be:

```js
const totalArray = [
    { id: 1, city: 'LONDON' },
    { id: 2, city: 'PARIS' },
    { id: 3, city: 'NEW YORK' },
    { id: 4, city: 'BERLIN' },
    { id: 5, city: 'MADRID' },
    { id: 6, city: 'ROME' },
    { id: 7, city: 'DUBLIN' },
    { id: 8, city: 'ATHENS' },
    { id: 9, city: 'ANKARA' },
    { id: 10, city: 'MOSCOW' },
]

const selectionArray = [
    { id: 6, city: 'ROME' },
    { id: 7, city: 'DUBLIN' },
    { id: 8, city: 'ATHENS' },
    { id: 9, city: 'ANKARA' },
    { id: 10, city: 'MOSCOW' },
];

const ids = selectionArray.map(({ id }) => id);
const filteredArray = totalArray.filter(({ id }) => !ids.includes(id));
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

in javascript you could get the index of a value using next:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
```

then to remove the that item:

```
arr.splice(a, 1);
```

Hope it could help if not please see:

[Love2Dev Removing Array Items By Value Using Splice](https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/)

Comment: This will work only if the objects points to the same reference, otherwise it won't.

Comment: Make sure this work for the OP case. Your example uses primitive types, not objects as it's the case of the OP